# constraints :subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How to use

```
constraints :subdomain => 'api',:format => :json do
end
```

and all others like www,nil and generics to redirect to www or nil (domain).

No generic subdomain, just api and only format json.

```
constraints :subdomain => 'api',:format => :json do
   root :to => "posts#index", :defaults => { :format => :json }
   get "posts" => "posts#index", :defaults => { :format => :json }
end
```

How to get default json if I access from api.domain.com/posts instead of /posts.json
This is not must have feature, but is cool. 
Now I need an redirect to domain if request is not json or not Found or render as json.

```
api.domain.com/posts
```

Should: 
    render as json, redirect to domain.com/post or show not found page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Rails Guide on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) it should go something like this.

```
constraints :subdomain => "api" do
  resources :your_resources_go_here, :defaults => { :format => :json }
end
```

Comment: Thats it. Somehow makes sense.